# How to to display images according to id (Filters)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to display images in a div according to select option (onclick = "DispImg())
I get 2 problem's

I store the images in array and I display all of theme and when you select an option it will automatically display the images that have the correct id .

and this is my script : I want to add to every image an id but the (setAttribute) method dosn't work and when you chose what id the script will display only the images that have the same id .

```js
var imgArray = new Array();

var corp = document.getElementById('range_imgs');

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.futura-sciences.com%2Fsciences%2Fdefinitions%2Funivers-etoile-3730%2F&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD";
imgArray[0].setAttribute("id" , "2");


imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvivre-marrakech.com%2Fblog%2Ffaire%2Fobserver-les-etoiles-a-marrakech%2F&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI";
imgArray[1].setAttribute("id" , "1");

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.numerama.com%2Fsciences%2F537548-au-lieu-detre-avalee-par-un-trou-noir-cette-etoile-sest-echappee-a-toute-vitesse.html&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAN";
imgArray[2].setAttribute("id" , "3");

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geowiki.fr%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3D%25C3%2589toile&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAS";
imgArray[3].setAttribute("id" , "2");

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.futura-sciences.com%2Fsciences%2Fquestions-reponses%2Fespace-quest-ce-quune-etoile-157%2F&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAX";
imgArray[4].setAttribute("id" , "1");


  for(var i=0;i<imgArray.length;i++){
    var imges = document.createElement("img");
      imges.src = imgArray[i].src;
      imges.style.marginRight = "15px";
      corp.appendChild(imges);
  }

  function appFilter(ele){

      var pics = document.querySelectorAll("img");

          if(pics.id == "1"){

          }

  }
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="allimgs" name="allimmages" >
      <option value="1et" onclick="appfilter(1)">img with id=1</option>
      <option value="2et" onclick="appfilter(2)">img with id=2</option>
      <option value="3et" onclick="appfilter(3)">img with id=3</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="range_imgs">
</div>
```

Thank you !!

Comment: please explain in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use `id` to store that value, because you are writing those to the DOM and all `id` properties must be unique.  Use a helper attribute like `data-id`.

```js
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.futura-sciences.com%2Fsciences%2Fdefinitions%2Funivers-etoile-3730%2F&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD";
imgArray[0].setAttribute("data-id", "2");

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvivre-marrakech.com%2Fblog%2Ffaire%2Fobserver-les-etoiles-a-marrakech%2F&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI";
imgArray[1].setAttribute("data-id", "1");

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.numerama.com%2Fsciences%2F537548-au-lieu-detre-avalee-par-un-trou-noir-cette-etoile-sest-echappee-a-toute-vitesse.html&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAN";
imgArray[2].setAttribute("data-id", "3");

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geowiki.fr%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3D%25C3%2589toile&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAS";
imgArray[3].setAttribute("data-id", "2");

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.futura-sciences.com%2Fsciences%2Fquestions-reponses%2Fespace-quest-ce-quune-etoile-157%2F&psig=AOvVaw2EmQPZg6y4m5Ap-jl4oKQv&ust=1582208140734000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjQluTm3ecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAX";
imgArray[4].setAttribute("data-id", "1");

const corp = document.getElementById('range_imgs');

// set margin
imgArray.forEach(
  img => img.style.setProperty("margin-right", "15px")
);

// append all to document
imgArray.forEach(
  img => corp.appendChild(img)
);

// hide/show functions
const hide = el => el.style.setProperty("display", "none");
const show = el => el.style.setProperty("display", "unset");

// get selected ID
const select = document.getElementById("allimgs");
const getSelectedId = () => select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-id");

// remove all images with non-selected IDs
const filterImages = () => document.querySelectorAll("#range_imgs > img").forEach(
  child => getSelectedId() == child.getAttribute("data-id") 
    ? show(child)
    : hide(child)
);

// run on pageload
window.addEventListener("load", filterImages);
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="allimgs" name="allimmages" onchange="filterImages(this)">
    <option value="1et" data-id="1">img with id=1</option>
    <option value="2et" data-id="2">img with id=2</option>
    <option value="3et" data-id="3">img with id=3</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="range_imgs">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for replay , i get this error "Cannot read property 'toString' of null"

Comment: Please refresh the page and hit "Run Code Snippet." It is working for me.

Comment: Man, if you can't even take working code and get it to function, then you're kind of beyond help. I can't wave a magic wand and make your local code work as expected, just adapt what I wrote.

Comment: i adapte the code now, i still have one question plz, is there a waya to show all images in the begening and then we can apply the filters thank you

Comment: Yes - the `window.addEventListener("load", filterImages)` call tells the window to filter the images as soon as the page is loaded. That was manually added so that it would filter them when you reload rather than just showing all of them. If you don't include that line, all the images will be on the page when you load it.

Comment: it works thank you man, well i just need to ask last question , is there a way to filter with 3 elements for ex with ( id - class - name )

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setAttribute you can replace with just .id but both should work fine

```
imgArray[x].id = x
```

your filter also won't work. replace with something like this

the pics variable is an array so pic.id won't work

```
var pics = document.querySelectorAll("img");
pics.forEach(function(pic) {
  if (pic.attr('id') == 2) {
    // do something
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you for ur comments, but this method did not work

Comment: in the first i tought like u this method will work like adding an src to img it will work for id but i was wrong it didnt work

Comment: i think your filter is the one with issues.

i'll update answer with your filter issues

Comment: the probleme is not with filter function is with the set of an id becuz all the images have not any id, and i prefere pure js

Comment: my code is still pure JS. if you try with just defining an image in console.log it using id and setattribute('id') works fine. you can even try console.logging the imageArray values, it should show the ids being present there.